# Cookie Java Project

Tags: java

I am a few weeks into my java class and one of my homework assignment I can't seem to figure out. Here is the assignment

"Display a menu of three kinds of cookie.  Prompt the user for what kind of cookie they want using the GetGoodInt(public static int GetGoodInt(int tLow, int tHigh) if the input is too high say to high, if its too low, say to low, if not a int display error) jar.
  Create a cookie, give it to the Oven to cook it, then give it to a Person to eat it.
!text bolded like **This** and then followed by declarations is a class that is both required and unchangeable!

**Cookie**

- boolean mCooked
- String mFlavor
- Cookie( String tFlavor )  // This is a constructor.  Note that when you have this, it won’t let you use the lazy default constructor.
- String toString() // This lets you output a cookie to the console.  Never call it manually.

**Oven**

- void Cook( Cookie tCookie ) // Just sets mCooked to true

**Person**

- void EatCookie( Cookie tCookie ) // If it is cooked, output the type and how good it is.  If it isn’t, print one sentence about the symptoms of salmonella.

*Sample Output:*

```
What type of cookie would you like?

1) Chocolate chip

2) Peanut butter

3) Oatmeal raisin

4

Not a choice.

r

Not a number

3

That was a great Oatmeal raisin cookie."
```

This is what I have coded so far but I am having trouble with what i assume isconstructor, so far everything I have tried gives me a Run time error.

Here is all my code

```
package mainpackage;

public class Cookie 
{
public Boolean mCooked;
public String mFlavor;
public Cookie(String tFlavor)
{
    tFlavor=mFlavor.toString();
}

public String toString()
{
    int i = Week9Jar.Input.GetGoodInt(1, 3);
    String tFlavor= Integer.toString(i);
    if(tFlavor=="1")
        mFlavor="Chocolate Chip";
    else if(tFlavor=="2")
        mFlavor="Peanut Butter";
    else if(tFlavor=="3")
        mFlavor="Oatmeal Raisin";
    return mFlavor;
}

}


package mainpackage;


public class Oven 
{
void Cook(Cookie tCookie)
{
tCookie.mCooked=true;
}


}

package mainpackage;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Week 9 Homework part I

    Cookie tCookie=null;
    Oven tOven= new Oven();
    Person tPerson = new Person();
    System.out.println("What type of Cookie would you like?");
    System.out.println("1) Chocolate Chip");
    System.out.println("2) Peanut Butter");
    System.out.println("3) Oatmeal Raisin");
    //get Type from user
    tCookie=new Cookie(Week9Jar.Input.GetGoodInt(1, 3));
    tOven.Cook(tCookie);
    tPerson.EatCookie(tCookie);

}

}
```

Comment: You forgot to check _how_ cooked the cookies are. You might get burnt cookies which have to be disposed of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constructor for `Cookie` is wrong: you take in `tFlavor` as an argument and assign a value to it, and after execution of the constructor, that value is lost. What you probably want is:

```
public Cookie(String tFlavor) {
    mFlavor = tFlavor;
}
```

You don't need to call `toString` on `String` objects: they're already strings!

Also, it's not good practice to access data members of a class from another class, even if it's from the same package:

```
public void Cook(Cookie cookie) {
    cookie.setCooked(true);
}
```

And add a `setCooked` method inside your class `Cookie`:

```
public void setCooked(boolean b) {
    mCooked = b;
}
```